# Adsense google error without adsense

Tags: javascript, adsense

[image]

Why i have this error, if i dont use any adsense on site?

Comment: Browser extension, included resource reaching for the url (e.g. iframe, script, stylesheet)... Try and watch the network tab, and see there's something in there? If this does not help, then remove parts of the page until you find what is generating the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of your Google Analytics code. Check your Analytics settings in the GA dashboard and check if you have enabled AdSense linking. Deactivating it should resolve this. To do so, go to Admin->Property->Adsense Linking  See: http://take.ms/eJTcX

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear all your browser cookies and then open your website with default settings. Since it is a google ads code, you would have used it previously and it got saved in your browser cookies and now it is popping up in your browser.